# Change test names for parameterized NUnit in VS Test Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, test-explorer

I am trying to integrate NUnit parameterized cross-browser tests using NUnit.  I want the tests to appear in the Test Explorer window, which I've accomplished using the NUnit3TestAdaptor, but I have no way of differentiating the different tests.  This is an example of the current TestFixture attributes on my class (following [this](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/C%23+Test+Setup+Example) example):

```
namespace Demo
{
    [TestFixture("Chrome", "72", "Windows 10", "", "")]
    [TestFixture("safari", "12.0", "iOS", "iPhone 8 Simulator", "portrait")]
    public class UNitTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void NUnitTestOne()
        {
            // Test Stuff
        }

        [Test]
        public void NUnitTestOne()
        {
            // Test Stuff
        }
}
```

This is how the tests appear in the Test Explorer:

```
-> Demo.UNitTests.NUnitTestOne
       NUnitTestOne
       NUnitTestOne
-> Demo.UNitTests.NUnitTestTwo
       NUnitTestTwo
       NUnitTestTwo
```

The problem is that I have no way of knowing which `NUnitTestOne` is a Chrome test vs iPhone test.  This is what I would prefer to see in the test explorer (or something like this)

```
-> NUnitTestOne
       Chrome
       iPhone
-> NUnitTestTwo
       Chrome
       iPhone
```

Ideally, something like this would be perfect:

```
[TestFixture("Chrome", "72", "Windows 10", "", ""), Name("Chrome")]
[TestFixture("safari", "12.0", "iOS", "iPhone 8 Simulator", "portrait"), Name("iPhone")]
```

But I could just be dreaming.  Is there a way to accomplish what I need?  Thanks!

edit:

When using TestName="Chrome", Test Explorer does this:

```
   NUnitTestOne
   NUnitTestOne
   NUnitTestTwo
   NUnitTestTwo
-> Demo.UNitTests.NUnitTestOne
       NUnitTestOne
       NUnitTestOne
-> Demo.UNitTests.NUnitTestTwo
       NUnitTestTwo
       NUnitTestTwo
```

Which is...weird.

edit again:

Used Category and it worked!  This is what was in the test explorer:

```
-> Chrome
       NUnitTestOne
       NUnitTestTwo
-> iPhone
       NUnitTestOne
       NUnitTestTwo
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close with `Name("Chrome")`. Instead, the property you want to set in the `TestFixture` attribute is `TestName`:

```
[TestFixture("Chrome", "72", "Windows 10", "", "", TestName = "Chrome")]
[TestFixture("safari", "12.0", "iOS", "iPhone 8 Simulator", "portrait", TestName = "iPhone")]
```

You can see all of the other properties available on that attribute [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/15175cba113b3937862d2f258320429658ce7440/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Attributes/TestFixtureAttribute.cs).

Comment: I added some code in the question showing what adding `TestName` did...it actually made it worse, which is strange.  Thank you though!

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs!  I used Category and it worked!  I put the results in the question.  Thanks!

Comment: What about when using `TestFixtureSource`? How do I set the test name then?